# Initialize bi-dimensional array of custom classes C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I' creating a program (just for didactic use) that solves the `8 queens puzzle`, where we should set 8 queens on a chessboard avoiding conflicts.

After applying some OOD I decided to create 3 classes : `Chessboard`, `Square` and `Queen`.
Obviously `Chessboard` is a composition of 64 (8x8) `Square`, we could argue on  `Queen`class utility but I think it could keep code cleaner and more organised.
Furthermore, when this will work I would like to create an UI so, in that case, having some queens would be useful.

By the way I started defining `Square` class :

```
class Square{
    int x;
    int y;
    bool avaible;
    public :
      Square(int ,int);
      bool isAvaible();
      void swapStatus() ;
    //Do I need destructor?
};
```

And until now all goes fine, but when I created `Chessboard` class the fun started because I'm still learning C++, started a few days ago and my brain is already bleeding. From what I remember of C and other informations I wrote this in ".hpp" :

```
//all fine here
    class Chessboard{
        Square squares[8][8];
    public:
        Chessboard();
    //I'm sure I need destructor here
    };
```

But the `.cpp` file... :

```
Chessboard::Chessboard(){ //Error 1 : Constructor for 'Chessboard' must explicitly initialize the member 'squares' which does not have a default constructor
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            squares[i][j] = new Square(i,j); //Error 2 : No viable overloaded '=' <- I have no idea of this
}
```

And for `destructor` (this is my first destructor) ? I have really no idea, I'm studying C++ alone for my sake and know nothing, just what I can read on books and internet.

This is just an idea, if you think I'm missing something more than a couple of errors please let me know.
I saw there are also lists (maybe?) in C++, I could also use them I don't have a specific needs of using arrays. But I would like to dynamic allocate `Squares`, just this.

Comment: An array of class objects has to default-initialize each entry, but your `Square` class doesn't have a default constructor. Also `new Square(i, j)` returns a `Square*` pointer, not a `Square` object. You could use a vector of vectors and [emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) your squares into them.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes square should have a constructor it's under "public : Square(int,int)" I didn't wrote implementation but it has one (or, at least, this is what  I think I did). Oh I thought new Square(i, j) returned an object not a pointer :S

Comment: @NathanPierson Oh ok now I understand what you meant with "default" thanks for the link